# Invariant subspace for adjoint representation

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group with $g = Lie(G)$ and $H$ be a maximal compact subgroup with $h= Lie(H)$. $G$ acts on $g$ by adjoint representation. By restriction so does $H$.

> Does $H$ keep $h$ invariant under this action? (What if $H$ is any subgroup in general?)

Comment: Quick comment: you should say *a* maximal compact subgroup, not "the".

Comment: Okay makes sense. But can you tell me how one can answer the problem?

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: At the level of Lie group $H$ acts on itself by conjugation. The adjoint is the derivative of this conjugation map. I was trying to spell out what $Ad_x(v)$ is where $v$ is in $h$ and $x$ in $H$. But I can't quite figure it out

Comment: Well now that I think about it... If we restrict the derivative map of conjugation by $x$ from $g \to g$ to $h$ then it does land in $h$ again. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. You can post an answer to your own question.

Comment: I want to ask a follow up : If there's some complement of $h$ in $g$ (maybe like an orthogonal complement wrt to Killing form in suitable scenarios) will $H$ also act on the complement? Or can the adjoint representation send elements of complement of $h$ back into $h$?

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person Note for that last bit, since you are requiring that $H$ is a maximal compact subgroup, there must be an orthogonal complement to $\mathfrak{h}$ since the Killing form will be nondegenerate on $\mathfrak{h}$. An arbitrary complement will not be preserved by $\operatorname{Ad} H$ and for an arbitrary subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}\leq \mathfrak{g}$, $\mathfrak{h}^\perp$ may not be complementary to $\mathfrak{h}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a Lie group and $H$ is any Lie subgroup then the restriction of $\mathrm{Ad}\colon G \to \mathrm{Aut}(\frak{g})$ to $H$ preserves $\frak{h}$. This is because the restriction of the conjugation action to $H$ preserves $H$.

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is equipped with an $\mathrm{Ad}(H)$-invariant bilinear form, e.g. the Killing form, then $\mathrm{Ad}(H)$ also preserves the perpendicular of $\frak{h}$ with respect to this form. This is because for all $h \in H$, $X \in \frak{h}$ and $Y \in \frak{h}^\perp$ we have
$$  \langle X, \mathrm{Ad}(h) Y \rangle = \langle \mathrm{Ad}(h^{-1})X,Y \rangle $$
with $\mathrm{Ad}(h^{-1})X \in \frak{h}$.

Comment: It is important to note that $\mathfrak{h}^\perp$ may not be a complement to $\mathfrak{h}$. For example a parabolic subalgebra $\mathfrak{p}$ has $\mathfrak{p}^\perp\leq\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: That's a good point. I replaced "complement" by "perpendicular" to lessen the confusion. Thanks!